β-Effect in vinylsilanes
I am reading about the β-silicon effect that stabilizes carbocation in the β-position [1, p. 672]:

The familiar hierarchy of carbocation stability—tertiary > secondary > primary—is due to the stabilization of the positive charge by donation of electron density from adjacent C–H or C–C bonds (their ﬁlled σ orbitals to be precise) that are aligned correctly with the vacant orbital.
The electropositive nature of silicon makes C–Si bonds even more effective donors: a silyl group β to a positive charge (i.e. attached to the next-door carbon) stabilizes a positive charge so effectively that the course of a reaction involving cationic intermediates is often completely controlled.
This is stabilization by σ donation.


However, if the silicon is in the vinylic position, I don't see how it can help in stabilizing the β-carbocation. The filled σ-bond cannot interact with the vacant p-orbital. Why does the book explain that it is stabilized by the vinylic position?
Reference

Clayden, J.; Greeves, N.; Warren, S. G. Organic Chemistry, 2nd ed.; Oxford University Press: Oxford; New York, 2012. ISBN 978-0-19-927029-3


$\ce{C-Si}$ bond is too long and thus weak. There is $\sigma$-donation effect in which the electrons of the C-Si bond get donated to the vinylic postion. The reason why it is vinylic is because the orbitals are effectively parallel (the empty pure p-orbital and the $\ce{C-Si}$ (as you posted in your picture))
You might feel this effect is similar to hyperconjugation in carbocation
